# Relationship between addressability/address space

Tags: system

A question was posed where if a computer has n-bit addressability and uses m bits to access a memory location, what is the size of memory in bytes? I am just confused on what the relationship between these two are, I believe you would multiply m * n to get the total bytes of memory

Answer (score 0):

2^n* m 
With n bits one can represent 2^n items.To find memory we raise the 2 to the number of n-bit addressability  and multiply by m bits